# Retrieve data from database filtered by pivot table Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got table structure like this:

users:

- id
- name

managers:

- id
- user_id

user_manager:

- manager_id
- user_id

vacations:

- user_id
- date_from...

My task is to fetch all data from vacations table where user (vacations.user_id) belongs to given manager id (managers.user_id) and that assigment is in pivot table user_manager. User can have many managers, manager can have many users. I've been trying to do this, but I've got stuck. My workaround was this:

```
        DB::table("vacations")
        ->leftJoin("users", function ($join) {
            $join->on("vacations.user_id", "=", "users.id");
        })
        ->leftJoin("user_manager", function ($join) {
            $join->on("user_manager.user_id", "=", "users.id");
        })
        ->where("user_manager.manager_id", "=", $id)
        ->get();
```

But I want to know a way to make this with eloquent model and all of it's fancy stuff.

Manager model:

```
class Manager extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'managers';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'employee_manager')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

User model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    public function managers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Manager::class, 'employee_manager')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `User` model's class name also `Manager` ? And to make it clear; you are trying to fetch an exact manager's users who has a vacation plan, did I understand it right?

Comment: My bad, just updated it in question. No my User class is named "User". I'm trying to fetch all Vacations assigned to User that is assigned to Manager (one user can have many managers). It's feature to accept user's request for vacations that are under You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get all `Vacation` records which created by a `User` which belongs to a specific `Manager`

It means you need to get all `Vacations` where `user_id` in that `Manager`
's `users()`

You can achieve this with a basic way like this;

```
$vacationsThatConcernTheManager = Vacation::whereIn('user_id', $manager->users()->pluck('id'))->get();
```

And if you want use directly something like `$manager->vacations()` you can use [hasManyThrough as described in documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

Add this relation to your `Manager` model;

```
public function vacations()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Vacation::class, User::class);
}
```

Comment: Thats a lot better than mine, but isn't there any way to make it with single eloquent method?

Comment: $manager = Manager::with(['users'])->where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)->first();
        $vacations = Vacation::whereIn('user_id', $manager->users()->pluck('user_id'))->get();

Comment: I think you can use `hasManyThrough` for it, I will check and update my answer.